# Bluetooth Magstripe card reader and printer

Tags: mobile, printing, bluetooth

I've found this awesome tool http://www.chargeanywheredirect.com/bluetooth-credit-card-reader-printer.html, but im not sure if i can use it to make my own mobile app cuz they dont have public api.

If anyone know this device better or know anyone what does the same funcions (Read card and print). Please help me thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Star Micronics has a printing SDK for Android and iOS.. Card reading is one of the functions. You can download it here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx.